# Conflict between french.sty and classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis, french

Good afternoon,

`classicthesis` is a very good package for theses and books. It seems, however, to have a problem handling French (or maybe it is the otherway around).
When loading French with `\usepackage{french}` I keep getting

```
! Improper \beginL.
<recently read> \beginL
```

just after some comment from `french.sty`.

This BeginL error does not seem to be referenced anywhere and I haven't been able to go around it. It crops up when stating:

```
\noindent \myName: \emph{\myTitle,}
\myDegree, \textcopyright\,\myUni, \myTime
```

or when trying to output the bibliographical references with:

```
printbibliography
```

Has anybody else had trouble with the combination of the packages `french` and `classicthesis`?

Here is a 'minimal' example which works when the command \usepackage{french} is commented out and doesn't work when it is used:

```
    \documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt %11pt,a4paper,%
                %french,% ngerman,american,%
                ]{scrreprt}

%********************************************************************
\usepackage{etex}       % To correct error :'! No room for a new \count .
\reserveinserts{28}     %  \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
    \usepackage{inputenc}
\input ../glyphtounicode.tex   %  to enable ligatured letters
\pdfgentounicode=1          %  to be searchable in pdf docs
% ****************************************************************************************************
% 1. Configure classicthesis for your needs here, e.g., remove "drafting" below
% in order to deactivate the time-stamp on the pages
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,%
                 pdfspacing,%floatperchapter,%linedheaders,%
             subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 2. Personal data and user ad-hoc commands
% ****************************************************************************************************
\newcommand{\myTitle}{Influence de l'information, les contrats et la météo sur la supply chain\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{Thèse en vue d'obtenir l'Habilitation à Diriger des Recherches\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDegree}{PhD\xspace}
\newcommand{\myName}{Xavier Brusset\xspace}
\newcommand{\myProf}{Samir Lamouri\xspace}
\newcommand{\myOtherProf}{Gilles Paché\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySupervisor}{Samir Lamouri\xspace}
\newcommand{\myFaculty}{TBS Research Centre\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDepartment}{Information, opérations et science de la décision\xspace}
\newcommand{\myUni}{Toulouse Business School\xspace}
\newcommand{\myLocation}{Toulouse\xspace}
\newcommand{\myTime}{Septembre 2015\xspace}
\newcommand{\myVersion}{version 0,1\xspace}

% ********************************************************************
% Setup, finetuning, and useful commands
% ********************************************************************
\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)

\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
    %backend=biber, %instead of bibtex
    backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
    language=auto,%
    style=numeric-comp,%
    %style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
    %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
    sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
    maxbibnames=3, % default: 3, et al.
    %backref=true,%
    natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}



\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
    \usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right

\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
    \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
    %\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms --> no longer working
    %\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\acsfont{#1}}

\usepackage{subfig}

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[minionpro]{classicthesis}
%********************************************************************
%                   Language option
%\usepackage{french}
%----------------------------------------------------------
%        Création de lettrines au début du texte
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{times} % Still required!

%-------------------------------------------------------
%*******************************************************
% Bibliographies
%*******************************************************
\addbibresource{../Xbib.bib}
%\addbibresource[label=ownpubs]{AMiede_Publications.bib}



\makeindex                  %       Index of words and expressions used
\begin{document}
%\newcommand*{frenchbsetup}[1]{}
%    \setkeys{FB}{#1}%
%        \@onlypreamble\frenchbsetup
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom

%
% *******************************************************************
%
%                           Frontmatter
%
% *******************************************************************
\pagenumbering{roman} %
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \large
        \hfill
        \vfill
        {\color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps{\myTitle}} \\ \bigskip
        \spacedlowsmallcaps{\myName}
        \vfill
        %\includegraphics[width=1.6cm]{} \\ \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \myDegree \\ \medskip
        \myDepartment \\
        \myFaculty \\
        \myUni \\ \bigskip
        \myTime
        \vfill
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
{ }\medskip
\hfill

\vfill

\noindent \myName: \emph{\myTitle,}
 \myDegree, \textcopyright\,\myUni, \myTime



\pagestyle{scrheadings} %

%\cleardoublepage\include{Contents}

\cleardoublepage\part{Préambule}%
%
%\cleardoublepage\include{acknowl_1}
%                           Preface
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\phantomsection
%\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Preface}{Preface}
\chapter*{Préface}\label{cha:preface}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{preface}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{preface}}
%\lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.25, loversize=0.25]{L}{\scshape a reconstruction}


%\noautomaticlettrine
%\let\lettrinehang=3

%\font\lettrinefont=cmr17 scaled\magstep3
%\let\lettrinefontname=Helvetica
%\lettrine[lines=2]{La reconstruction}
%\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontfamily{sf}\fontseries{bm}\fontshape{sl}\color[gray]{0.5}}% \fontfamily{times}\fontseries{bx}
%\fontshape{sl}
\lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.25, loversize=0.25]{L}{\scshape a reconstruction} d'un parcours de recherche fait de choix délibérés et aussi d'opportunités saisies, permet de relire et d'articuler autour d'un fil directeur les thèmes traités et les questions étudiées, en dépassant la diversité de ses propres travaux afin d'y retrouver la cohérence de pensée et d'axe. Le fil directeur qui sous-tend les recherches menées au cours des quatorze dernières années est: <<atteindre l'efficience dans la supply chain à travers le partage d'information et les contrats>>.
% *******************************************************************
%
%                           Mainmatter
%
% *******************************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%
\cleardoublepage\part{Thèse}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Introduction}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}\label{cha:intro}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Introduction}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Introduction}}

\lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.25, loversize=0.25]{L}{\scshape a diade} du texte. Du texte recherche fait de choix délibérés et aussi d'opportunités saisies, permet de relire et d'articuler autour d'un fil directeur les thèmes traités et les questions étudiées, en dépassant la diversité de ses propres travaux afin d'y retrouver la cohérence de pensée et d'axe. Le fil directeur qui sous-tend les recherches menées au cours des quatorze dernières années est: <<atteindre l'efficience dans la supply chain à travers le partage d'information et les contrats>>.


\section{Avant la signature du contrat}\label{sec:avant}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your document. Where can we get the `french` package? Is it the `e-french` package?

Comment: I made a small example with just `\documentclass{scrbook}`, `\usepackage{french}` and `\usepackage{classicthesis}`, with a word in the `document` environment. No error.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, yes it is the e-french package which is used by adding \usepackage{french}.

Comment: Here is a 'minimal' example which works when the command \usepackage{french} is commented out and doesn't when it is used:

Comment: Is that related to minionPro or the glyphtounicode stuff? I don't have them, ignoring it, everything works just fine.

Comment: @Johannes_B when I take out both MinionPro and \glyphtounicode, I still get the error. I believe it has to do with all the adjustments that the frenchle module does which conflicts in some way either with classicthesis or with koma-cript...

Comment: As i said, i don't get an error. Try updating your TeX distribution. If `minionpro` and the unicode stuff are irrelevant, you can delete that from the example. Test out the other stuff as well. In the very end, your example will be about five to ten lines long to show the problem.

Comment: The file `glyphtounicode.tex` is in every up-to-date (and complete) TeX distribution, so it should be `\input{glyphtounicode}`. Other than that, removing the `minionpro` option gives no error. I don't think having `minionpro` is relevant, so you probably have an outdated distribution.

Comment: I updated my MiKTeX installation (noticed that there was a new classicthesis version dated this august), but I still get the error.

Comment: @Xavier_B Even if you remove the `minionpro` option?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get things working by using babel with frenchb:

```
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
```

This works by setting in French the words Part I: Première partie, and generally making a nice presentation. I also had to change the way the authors' names were capaitalized in the citations, as this was too ugly, by adding the command:

```
    \DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{#1}}
```

in the preamble.

I may not have ALL the French style idiosyncrasies, but it is well enough for me and it enables me to use the very nice package classicthesis!